# JAVA SE stopped working while connecting to project on QC/ALM Server from java application using OTAClient and com4j

Tags: java, hp-quality-center, com4j, hp-alm

I tried connecting java with QC with help of OTAClient and com4j. It is getting connected to server and then the login was also successful. But when it comes to connecting to a particular project and domain it takes some time, works and then says "JAVA(TM) SE Has Stopped Working".

```
itdc.connect("Domain","project");
```

When I check the details it is mentioned that OTAClient.dll is the fault. Can you please give me a solution to overcome this?

Comment: Could you please add the error trace to your question?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post I am getting the message the the JAVA(TM) SE has stopped working. When I look into details it is mentioned "Faulty module: OTAClient.dll". No error trace in eclipse console.